# Error Adding Plugin To Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

The problem is when i add plugin using the command, (

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

) i get the error `"project directory could not be found!"`. I have tried to install plugin to a existing android project .I am using phone gap 3.0..please help.

Comment: Iam on the projects's root directory.

Comment: Did you resolve your it? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Try it with cordova, for example: `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git`

Answer (score 0):

I see a syntax error in command, it should be like this:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-network-information.git
```

Comment: sorry the original command is same as you mentioned,my doubt is were to use this which directory???if we add add this command will the plugin embed in original android project or should we take new build???